# How can I know what requires yum to install those dependencies?

Tags: linux, dependencies, yum, fedora-21

Doing `yum update` I get the following:

```
 kernel-modules-extra              x86_64 3.18.7-100.fc20                       @updates/20
                                                                                        8.3 M
Installing for dependencies:
 GeoIP-GeoLite-data                noarch 2015.04-1.fc21                        updates 347 k
 GeoIP-GeoLite-data-extra          noarch 2015.04-1.fc21                        updates  23 M
 R-core                            x86_64 3.1.3-1.fc21                          updates  48 M
 R-core-devel                      x86_64 3.1.3-1.fc21                          updates 100 k
 dleyna-connector-dbus             x86_64 0.2.0-4.fc21                          updates  24 k
 dleyna-core                       x86_64 0.4.0-3.fc21                          fedora   30 k
 dleyna-server                     x86_64 0.4.0-7.fc21                          updates  70 k
 geoipupdate                       x86_64 2.2.1-2.fc21                          updates  33 k
 lz4                               x86_64 r128-2.fc21                           updates  68 k
```

I want to know what requires `R-core` as i built it myself and do not want it to be installed... There must be something I must delete...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rpm -q --whatrequires R-core` might tell you.

If it doesn't it might be a library or binary dependency and so you'll need to run `yum whatrequires` on the various libraries/binaries listed in the output from `rpm -q --provides R-core` and/or `rpm -ql R-core`.

That being said the fact that you built R yourself isn't going to help you in this case as rpm doesn't know anything about that (nor is it likely to be installed in a location that official Fedora packages can use).

If you were to build R as an rpm yourself you might be able to get that to satisfy this dependency (whatever it is) correctly though.

Comment: As an additional note: if you're building R (or some other package yourself) as an alternate stack (newer version, different options, whatever), it's usually best to put this in your own home directory (or `/usr/local`) and treat it as its own universe, leaving the system packages as they are — so, there should be no harm in having the system package installed even if you're not using it directly.